# Eloquent detalle de las relaciones

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Estoy tratando de crear una relación de muchos a muchos sobre un mismo modelo, en la que intervienen, además, datos de otros modelos en la tabla pivote. No pongo las estructuras ni los modelos, porque lo que busco es resolver el escenario por mí misma, pero sí necesito que me ayudéis diciéndome donde puedo encontrar docu más detallada sobre las relaciones. En la docu oficial, los ejemplos que hay no usan todos los argumentos que los métodos tienen en el `HasRelationships.php` del propio Laravel. Y, la verdad, es que mirando el código, los argumentos de las firmas de los métodos son un poco confusos.

Si alguien sabe donde encontrar documentación más profunda y detallada (yo he googleado mucho y no la encuentro), os lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentaré responder a las múltiples preguntas:

1. No existe una documentación más profunda y detallada que la oficial, al menos no la conozco, y no creo que alguien la hiciera a ese nivel, sin algún interés o beneficio.

   Los otros recursos que pueden tal vez guiar aparte de la documentación son:

   - StackOverflow
   - El blog del primer empleado de Laravel (Mohammed Said) https://www.divinglaravel.com/
   - [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/)
   - [Styde](https://styde.net/) (en español)
   - [Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/)
   - [Código de Laravel en Githu](https://github.com/laravel/framework)b, el cual está muy bien documentado en los comentarios del mismo.
2. Por defecto Eloquent no viene diseñado para trabajar con más de dos modelos en una relación muchos a muchos, es considerado una excepción y por ese motivo no encontrarás documentación al respecto, al menos no de manera oficial.

   Hay varias formas de poder hacerlo sin salirse de los estándares de Laravel, pero depende de lo que necesites lograr específicamente:

   - Definir relaciones entre «grupos» de dos tablas, proporcionando los parámetros adicionales para el CRUD, en caso de ser necesario.
   - Definir una relación many-to-many y agregar la información de la tercera (hay muchas formas de hacerlo), aunque puede ser un poco enredado.
   - Crear un modelo para la tabla pivote, y posteriormente definir relaciones one-to-many entre los tres modelos que comentas y la tabla pivote.

Mi mejor documentación siempre ha sido el código, en los métodos de los traits, interfaces, etc. he encontrado lo que necesito, o al menos una idea de cómo poder solucionar los problemas con lo que hay.